# Value after emit does not change

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

I have a parent and a child component. In my parent component I will fire a watched method in my child element. In there I have an emit which brings me back to the following seperat method in the parent component.

```
export default {
    setup() {
       var allItemsChecked= ref(false)

      return {
         allItemsChecked 
      }
    },
   
   methods:{
    showButton(checked) {
       this.allItemsChecked = checked //checked has the value "true" 
       console.log(this.allItemsChecked)
     },
   }
}
```

This method should display the following button:

```
 <div v-if="allItemsChecked">
       <div class="d-flex flex-justify-center pt-5">
            <button class="button large dark outline"><span class="mif-truck"> save</span></button>
       </div>
 </div>
```

The console.log displays the correct value "true" but the value in the DOM is not changing.

I assigned a ref to the allItemsChecked variable.
Is it possible that you cant emit to the parent in a watched method ?

I am thankful for any help or hints.

Comment: @seriously What do you mean by display command? I simply assign ```allItemsChecked``` with true. Then because of the ref the Value in the dom should also change to true which results in showing the button.
I tried to add a if-Statement which is true but for the dom the value is false

Answer (score 0):

If `allItemsChecked` is a `ref`, you need to use `.value` to set the value in a reactive way

```js
 showButton(checked) {
       this.allItemsChecked.value = checked //checked has the value "true" 
       console.log(this.allItemsChecked)
 },
```

if you're getting the error `Cannot create property 'value' on boolean 'false'`, it means you've already assigned it incorrectly somewhere else. Find all instances of `allItemsChecked =` and replace with `allItemsChecked.value =`

Comment: I  edited my question to hopefully make the question clearer. I am sorry if my question was misleading in any way. I get an error ( Cannot create property 'value' on boolean 'false') if I use ```.value``` on ```allItemsChecked```

Comment: look into other instances where the value is being assigned

Comment: The value ```allItemsChecked```gets only assigned in the ```showButton``` Method